# Use NSOpenpanel and NSfilemanager to find contents of directory

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to objective-c so please excuse my lack of knowledge. I have a snippet of code here that I can't seem to get working properly.  What I'd like to do is present a directory selection panel upon a button click. Once the user selects a directory I'd like to make an array of everything in the directory. Eventually I want to use this array to have a list of sub-directories and files (everything in the directory the user selects) to be copied to another location.

I have a warning that says Instance method '-contentsofdirectoryaturl:options:error' not found (return type defaults to id). I'm not exactly sure what that means or how to fix it and I suspect that this is my problem. Any advice provided would be great. Thanks!

```
- (IBAction)selectfiles:(id)sender {

NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

[openPanel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
[openPanel setCanChooseFiles:NO];
[openPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];

if ( [openPanel runModal] == NSOKButton ) {

    NSArray *accountPath = [openPanel URLs];
    NSLog (@"%@", accountPath);

    NSFileManager *filemgr;
    filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSArray *contents;
    contents = [filemgr contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:accountPath options:(NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles) error:nil];

    }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:` has an additional argument `includingPropertiesForKeys:` which you have omitted. That is why the compiler warns you. That argument is a list of properties you want to be prefetched. In the simplest case, you can specify an empty array.

Another error is that `[openPanel URLs]` returns an *array* of URLs, even if only one item is selected.

So your code should look like this:

```
NSURL *accountPath = [[openPanel URLs] objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog (@"%@", accountPath);

NSFileManager *filemgr;
filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSArray *contents;
contents = [filemgr contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:accountPath
    includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray array]
    options:(NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles)
    error:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to do the job!